# Plotting contours in python in Matplotlib

Tags: python, data-analysis, contour

I am a beginner for data analysis or analytics,
My question here is, I have grid points (x and y) of a grid or a mesh and I have a corresponding temperature value for every grid point, I have to generate a 2D contour plot of temperature  using that data which is present in an excel, Any idea on how to start on this topic, this would be of great help to me.

Comment: Read about [`contour()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) by matplotlib. This [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html) is a good start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of contour map from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x)

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y) # temperature

plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar()
```

output :

[image: Color map]

matplotlib is good, but [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/) is powerful and easier, you should try it.